# Keras: Visualize ImageDataGenerator Output

Tags: image-processing, plot, colors, keras

I would like to see what my ImageDataGenerator yields to my network.

**Edit:**
removed the channel_shift_range, accidently left it in the code

### Generator

```
genNorm = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, width_shift_range=0.1, 
       height_shift_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True)
```

### Get Batches

```
batches = genNorm.flow_from_directory(path+'train', target_size=(224,224),
      class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64)

x_batch, y_batch = next(batches)
```

### Plot Images

```
for i in range (0,32):
    image = x_batch[i]
    plt.imshow(image.transpose(2,1,0))
    plt.show()
```

### Result

[Generator Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zufrN.png)

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The strange colors result from your channel shift. Do you really need that to augment your samples? Is a value of 10 (=very high) really what you want?

In addition to that: Another and likely more efficient way of checking what your generator yields is to set a directory with `save_to_dir` (parameter of flow/flow from directory function). In that you´ll find all the images that have been transformed and been delivered to your fit/flow function.

**Edit:**

You still somehow seem to invert your images during processing or while displaying them. I assume the original images look more like this:

[image]

Save the results of your ImageDataGenerator to a directory and compare these with the results that you see with `plt.show`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried a lot and left it accidently in the code... still the same issue.

Comment: If you save to a directory with save_to_dir and compare that to your plt.imshow screenshots – do the images look the same? You still seem to have inverted the images (see edit).

Comment: You may have normalized the images by diving by 255 prior to visualizing them

Answer (score 2):

Try this; change the generator as follow:

```
import numpy as np

def my_preprocessing_func(img):
    image = np.array(img)
    return image / 255

genNorm = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, width_shift_range=0.1, 
       height_shift_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True, 
       preprocessing_function=my_preprocessing_func)
```

That worked for me,

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

keras uses the image operation with Pillow backend, which comes with 'RGB' format default. So you don't need to reverse the channel axis in your `plt.imshow()`.

Only in `cv2.imread()` (which is 'BGR' default), you may need `plt.imshow(img[:, :, ::-1])` to display the right image.

BR