# Plot images from Image Generator

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, data-augmentation

I'm trying to plot the images created by my image generator. So far this is the code of my data given to the generator:

```
train_img_gen = train_img_data_gen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(training_dir, 'images'),
                                                   target_size=(img_h, img_w),
                                                   batch_size=bs, 
                                                   class_mode=None, # Because we have no class subfolders in this case
                                                   shuffle=True,
                                                   interpolation='bilinear',
                                                   seed=SEED)
#edited part following the already existing answer on stackoverflow
x_batch, y_batch = next(train_img_gen)
for i in range (0,32):
    image = x_batch[i]
    plt.imshow(image.transpose(2,1,0))
    plt.show()
```

I followed this question: [Keras images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797852/keras-visualize-imagedatagenerator-output), but without any success.

How can i plot (for example) the first n images generated by my `imageGenerator`?

**EDIT :**

I added the code used in the above mentioned question, but i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1a18ce1c1a76> in <module>
     54 valid_gen = zip(valid_img_gen, valid_mask_gen)
     55 
---> 56 x_batch, y_batch = next(train_img_gen)
     57 for i in range (0,32):
     58     image = x_batch[i]

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: did you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Edited with error

Comment: assing result to one variable `result = next(train_img_gen)` and print it `print(result)` - it seems it returns only one value, not two as you expect. Maybe you will need on `x_batch = next(train_img_gen)`.

Comment: result returns a matrix of elements with this shape: (4, 256, 256, 3)

Comment: so you may have 4 images with size `256x256` and RGB (3) colors. You can try to display `plt.imshow( result[0] )` `plt.imshow( result[1] )`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end i solved the problem, it was a problem with dimensions.

The working code is:

```
x= train_img_gen.next()
for i in range(0,4):
    image = x[i]
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

The generator returns for each iteration a matrix with shape `(4,256,256,3)`, which means that we have 4 images of size 256x256 and 3 channels (RGB).

The `ImageDataGenerator` works with "blocks" of 4 images at time(at least in this case, i have no official reference about how many images does it loads everytime), since its main purpose is to load images on the fly while training the model (avoiding to pre-load a huge amount of data in memory).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(train_img_gen)):
    batch = train_img_gen[i]

    if batch is made of x and y: #this line is pseudocode
        x, y = batch

    if batch has only x: #this line is peudocode
        x = batch 

    print('images in batch:', len(x))

    for image in x:
        plot
```

Comment: What do you mean with "It's made of x and y"?

Comment: Images and classes