# Plotting an image after using keras preprocessing

Tags: python, image, keras

I have a problem in which there are 8 classes with approximately 2000 images. I want to get the images from the folder to later use them in a neural network. There only is one class per image.

In a dataframe variable called `training_set` I have a column with the name of the images and in the other its label. This was made using the csv given to me. Per example one line of the dataframe would be: img001.jpg   cat

After creating the variable `training_set`(which has the 2000 images names and labels), I use the function `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_dataframe` to fetch the images to the program as you can see below.

```
train_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/2)

train_generator = train_dataGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = training_set, directory="",x_col="Images", y_col="Labels", class_mode="categorical", 
                                                    target_size=(224,224), batch_size=32)
```

The variable `train_generator` is of type `python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataFrameIterator`.
My question is does `train_generator` have all the 2000 images? How could I plot only one of those images? If by any means I should use other functions instead of the ones I mentioned please say.

Comment: Does [plot-images-from-image-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217031/plot-images-from-image-generator) answer your question?

Comment: ah yes, @Frightera thanks. On another note, in the case I don't want to change the images, can I still use the functions above described?

Comment: You can use ImageDataGenerator to load your images also, that would be no problem.